# How can I Select which Environment to run from a single stage in an Azure Pipeline with conditionals or another way

Tags: azure-devops, conditional-statements, yaml, pipeline

I have a pipeline in Azure Devops that runs two Environments, QA and DEV and I need it to select on Azure DevOps which environment to run from a single stage instead of using two separate stages for QA and DEV

Here's the stage code that I'm using for both environments:

```
# BUILD ENVIRONMENTS
- stage: build_envs
  dependsOn: quality_control
  displayName: Build Envs
  condition: |
   or 
    (
      and(eq(variables.isQa, true), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')),  eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual'),
      and(eq(variables.isDev, true), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')),  eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual')
    )
  jobs:
  - job: Job_build 
    displayName:  Application Build
    steps:
    - ${{ if eq(variables.isQa, true) }}:
      - checkout: backend-qa
        path: enext-data-platform-backend
      - script: rm -rf enext-data-platform-backend/enext-data-platform-frontend
      - checkout: frontend-qa
        path: enext-data-platform-backend/enext-data-platform-frontend
          #submodules: true
      - script: |
          ls -la $(Pipeline.Workspace)/enext-data-platform-backend
          ls -la $(Pipeline.Workspace)/enext-data-platform-backend/enext-data-platform-frontend
      - powershell: |
          Write-Host "##vso[build.addbuildtag]qa"
      #displayName: Application Build DEV
    - ${{ elseif eq(variables.isDev, true) }}:
      - checkout: backend-dev
        submodules: true
      - script: git rev-parse HEAD
      - script: ls -la   
      - powershell: |
          Write-Host "##vso[build.addbuildtag]dev"
      #displayName: 'Build Tag'

    - task: npmAuthenticate@0
      displayName: npm Authenticate enext-data-platform-backend/.npmrc
      inputs:
        ${{ if eq(variables.isQa, true) }}:
          workingFile: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/enext-data-platform-backend/.npmrc
        ${{ elseif eq(variables.isDev, true) }}:
          workingFile: .npmrc
      

    - task: npmAuthenticate@0
      displayName: npm Authenticate enext-data-platform-backend/enext-data-platform-frontend/.npmrc
      inputs:
        ${{ if eq(variables.isQa, true) }}:
          workingFile: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/enext-data-platform-backend/enext-data-platform-frontend/.npmrc
        ${{ elseif eq(variables.isDev, true) }}:
          workingFile: enext-data-platform-frontend/.npmrc
    
    - task: Docker@0
      displayName: 'Build an image'
      inputs:
        command: 'buildAndPush'
        containerregistrytype: 'Container Registry'
        imageName: "$(Build.Repository.Name):$(Build.BuildId)"
        ${{ if eq(variables.isQa, true) }}: 
          buildContext: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/enext-data-platform-backend/
          Dockerfile: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/enext-data-platform-backend/Dockerfile
        ${{ elseif eq(variables.isDev, true) }}:
          buildContext: enext-data-platform-backend
          Dockerfile: 'Dockerfile'

    - script: |
        set -x
        env
        pwd
        echo "CONTAINER_APP=$(Build.Repository. Name):$(Build.BuildId)" > artifact.txt
        source ./artifact.txt
        docker save $CONTAINER_APP > container.tar
        ls -la
      displayName: 'Shell Script: APP'

    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
      displayName: 'Publish Pipeline Artifact - container id'
      inputs:
        targetPath: artifact.txt
        artifact: artifact

    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
      displayName: 'Publish Pipeline Artifact - container data'
      inputs:
        targetPath: container.tar
        artifact: container

    - task: Docker@0
      displayName: 'Build an image'
      inputs:
        command: 'buildAndPush'
        containerregistrytype: 'Container Registry'
        imageName: "$(Build.Repository.Name):$(Build.BuildId)"
        ${{ if eq(variables.isQa, true) }}: 
          buildContext: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/enext-data-platform-backend/
          Dockerfile: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/enext-data-platform-backend/Dockerfile
        ${{ elseif eq(variables.isDev, true) }}:
          buildContext: enext-data-platform-backend
          Dockerfile: 'Dockerfile'

    - script: | 
        echo "CONTAINER_KNEX=$(Build.Repository.Name):$(Build.BuildId)" > artifact-knex.txt
        source ./artifact-knex.txt
        docker save $CONTAINER_KNEX > container-knex.tar
        ls -la 
      displayName: 'Shell Script: knex'

    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
      displayName: 'Publish Pipeline Artifact - container id: knex'
      inputs:
        targetPath: artifact-knex.txt
        artifact: artifact-knex
    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
      displayName: 'Publish Pipeline Artifact - container data: knex'
      inputs:
        targetPath: container-knex.tar
        artifact: container-knex 

  - job: dbschema
    displayName:  DB Schema
    steps:
    - checkout: dbschema
      submodules: true
    - script: ls -la

    - task: Docker@0
      displayName: 'Build an image'
      inputs:
        command: 'buildAndPush'
        buildContext: enext-matflow-dbschema
        containerregistrytype: 'Container Registry'
        imageName: "$(Build.Repository.Name):$(Build.BuildId)"
        Dockerfile: 'Dockerfile'

    - script: |
        echo "CONTAINER_DB=$(Build.Repository.Name):$(Build.BuildId)" > sql_artifact.txt
        source ./sql_artifact.txt
        docker save $CONTAINER_DB > sql_container.tar
        ls -la
      displayName: 'Shell Script: DB'
    
    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
      displayName: 'Publish Pipeline Artifact - sql container id'
      inputs:
        targetPath: sql_artifact.txt
        artifact: sql_artifact

    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
      displayName: 'Publish Pipeline Artifact - sql container data'
      inputs:
        targetPath: sql_container.tar
        artifact: sql_container
```

And in Azure DevOps when I run the pipeline looks like this:

[image]

And it runs the two environments at the same time, and what I'm trying to do is that I can select on Azure DevOPs which Env to run like this:

[image]

As of now I'm trying with conditionals but I'm very lost.

I've been  trying with conditionals but I'm really new to Azure and I don't know how to set them in a correct way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Stages to run` function **only** displays each `- stage` under `stages` of a YAML definition. From the YAML definition you shared, it only contained one single stage `- stage: build_envs` and `${if}` insertions will not expand one stage into two.

For this, you may consider using `${each}` expression to expand the stage. Please refer to the sample below. Since there are only two environments, you may also consider evaluating the value of an **object** type of parameter.

```
parameters:
- name: Envs
  type: object
  default:
    - QA
    - DEV
  
stages:
- stage: quality_control
  displayName: Quality Control
  jobs:
  - job: Job1
    steps:
    - checkout: none
# BUILD ENVIRONMENTS
- ${{ each env in parameters.Envs }}:
  - stage: build_${{ env }}
    dependsOn: quality_control
    displayName: Build ${{ env }}
    condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual')
    jobs:
    - job: Job_build 
      displayName:  Application Build
      steps:
      - ${{ if eq(env, 'QA') }}:
        - checkout: backend-qa
          path: enext-data-platform-backend
        - script: echo ${{ env }}
      - ${{ elseif eq(env, 'Dev') }}:
        - checkout: backend-dev
          submodules: true
        - script: echo ${{ env }}

- stage: publish_artifact
  displayName: Pulish Artifact
  jobs:
  - job: Job1
    steps:
    - checkout: none
```

[image]

Besides, since your pipeline will use either `QA` or `DEV` environment and the `build_envs` stage is only executed when the pipeline is manually triggered, you may consider setting `Envs` parameter value at queue time and run different sets of steps accordingly. Here is another sample for your reference.

```
parameters:
- name: Envs
  type: string
  default: QA
  values:
  - QA
  - DEV

stages:
- stage: quality_control
  displayName: Quality Control
  jobs:
  - job: Job1
    steps:
    - checkout: none
# BUILD ENVIRONMENTS
- stage: build_${{ parameters.Envs}}
  dependsOn: quality_control
  displayName: Build ${{ parameters.Envs }}
  condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual')
  jobs:
  - job: Job_build 
    displayName:  Application Build
    steps:
    - ${{ if eq(parameters.Envs, 'QA') }}:
      - checkout: backend-qa
        path: enext-data-platform-backend
      - script: echo ${{ parameters.Envs}}
    - ${{ elseif eq(parameters.Envs, 'Dev') }}:
      - checkout: backend-dev
        submodules: true
      - script: echo ${{ parameters.Envs }}
```

[image]